# Hook for module activation and deactivation

Tags: 7, hooks

I am trying to execute a function in my module when the module is activated or deactivated by the user. It seems that there is a hook for this in Drupal 7, but not in Drupal 6. It is possible to do this with a workaround in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 4):

The docs say that [`hook_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) and [`hook_disable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) are for versions 5-7.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492385/drupal-hook-that-runs-when-modules-are-installed-and-uninstall/5492510#5492510